# unsigned long long arithmetics

Tags: c++, visual-c++, long-integer, unsigned

I'd like to multiply two `unsigned integers` but I want the result to be in an `unsigned long long` variable

```
unsigned long long M;
unsigned int X;
unsigned int Y;

X = 999999;
Y = 9990;
M = X * Y;
```

`M` should be `9989990010` but for some reason it keeps being `1400055418`

I've been troubled with this for a week now, and I think I reached the point where I want to cry!

Comment: 9989990010LL % (1 << 32) == 1400055418LL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to cast the `X` and `Y` to `long long`.

```
M = (unsigned long long)X * Y;
```

Enough to cast one of them the result will be based on the larger type.

Otherwise the result will be `int`, hence the overflow. It will be casted to `long long` on assignment, but that would be too late:-)

Answer (score 3):

Both X and Y are only ints, so the type of the expression X*Y is an int. The number is converted to long long after the multiply is already done. Make X and Y long longs and you'll get the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Cast at least one of them to `unsigned long long`. The other will be cast (promoted) automatically. The problem here is: How do the compiler knows if you want the truncated result of multiplying `int` values or the result of not truncating, `long long` value?